# keep outer loop instance waiting until inner loop with async completes

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, async-await

I am a new comer to javascript world and I am coming from a Java background. This whole async await thing is completely new to me.

In my current assignment, I have something similar to what I am describing below.

I have two loops which are nested. In the inner loop, I am doing some async stuff. The outer loop iteration must wait until the inner loop complete its task.

This is what I have coded so far.

```
var bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var foo = [1, 2];

await Promise.all(bar.map(async (barItem, barIndex, barArray) => {

  console.log('OUTER VALUE = ' + barItem);

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    foo.forEach(async (value, index, array) => {
      console.log(value);

      this.qrvalue = "payLoad";

      while (!document.querySelector(".qrcode img")) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
        console.log("waiting for qr");
      }
      console.log("QR element is available");

      if (index === array.length - 1) resolve();
    });
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('All done!');
  });

}));
```

I need console log to be like this.

```
OUTER VALUE = a
1
waiting for qr
QR element is available
2
waiting for qr
QR element is available
OUTER VALUE = b
1
waiting for qr
QR element is available
2
waiting for qr
QR element is available
..
..
..
```

But what it prints is,

```
OUTER VALUE = a
1
2
OUTER VALUE = b
1
2
..
..
waiting for qr
QR element is available
waiting for qr
QR element is available
..
..
```

Can I know how should I do this to get the desired output? Why doesn't the outer loop wait even if await is there? Thank You..!

Comment: That `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    foo.forEach(async (value, index, array) => {` is the problem. Use the same approach to looping that you used on the outer loop.

Comment: Also, if you want these loops to be run sequentially, you shouldn't use `Promise.all`+`map`, use a normal `for` loop instead.

Comment: I tried normal for loop also. But couldn't get it done.